# PendingIntent start activity canceledException

Tags: android-intent, android-pendingintent, start-activity

I am really stcuk. The code below, works when I try to start an activity in one application while it generates a canceled exception when I try to start an activity in another application. I have searched for potential solutions including

[Notification pendingIntent contentIntent fails when activity calls finish()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509156/notification-pendingintent-contentintent-fails-when-activity-calls-finish)

I also looked at the PendingIntent.java source code. The canceled exception is called when

"     * @throws CanceledException Throws CanceledException if the PendingIntent
* is no longer allowing more intents to be sent through it.
"

Below, you will find my code. I would appreciate any advice/pointers towards a solution of this problem.

Thanks,

Alex Donnini

```
private static Intent intentForMainActivityFromNetGuard = new Intent();
private static PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    PREPARE TO START MainActivityFromNetGuard - START
    intentForMainActivityFromNetGuard = new Intent();
    intentForMainActivityFromNetGuard.setComponent(new ComponentName("ca.uwaterloo.crysp.privacyguard", "ca.uwaterloo.crysp.privacyguard.Application.Activities.ActivityMainFromNetGuard"));
    intentForMainActivityFromNetGuard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intentForMainActivityFromNetGuard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intentForMainActivityFromNetGuard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
   Random generator = new Random();
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ActivityMain.getInstance(), generator.nextInt(), intentForMainActivityFromNetGuard, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

                        try {
                            pendingIntent.send();
                        } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {

                            Log.i(TAG, " - updateAcces - Attempt to trigger execution of MainActivityFromNetGuard FAILED --- ");

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Wrong component information.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it solved the problem.